# Writing a query to delete a node that has not pinged the server for 3 minutes

Tags: java, sql

After every 5 seconds a node pings the server. If the ping is successful, node's time-stamp gets updated into the server database.After every 3 minutes server checks if there is any time-stamp older than 3 minutes. If it founds any,it removes the node from it's database.

Now the problem. I am unable to implement this query. For example I want it in a rather simple way like :

```
// Get the server time-stamp in milliseconds

select LastPingedAt from JustPinged where LastPingedAt > 3 Minutes"

// If it finds any,delete each of them from the database.
```

---

```
The logic :
Let the server's time stamp at the point of checking be 'serverStamp'
Let the node's time stamp (time in milliseconds when it last pinged) in the 
database's table be 'nodeStamp'.

If ( serverStamp - nodeStamp > 3 minutes)
// Delete those nodes
If( severStamp - nodeStamp < 3 minutes)
// retain those nodes
```

I am unable to design a the query to implement further.

At any point, `JustPinged` table looks like :

```
--------------------------|----------------------
NodesThatJustPinged       |          LastPingedAt
--------------------------|-----------------------
 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx          |          1355406367402
--------------------------|-----------------------
 yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy          |          1355406421277
--------------------------|-----------------------
```

The time is in milliseconds as from `new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to get all of the records and process them in your program.  This can be done with a single SQL statement.  All you need to execute is a statement like this:

```
delete from JustPinged where CurrentTime - LastPingedAt > 180000;
```

So you just need to build the string in Java, interpolating the current time value, and run it:

```
String query = "delete from JustPinged where " +
     [your current time variable here] + " - LastPingedAt > 180000;";

your_statement_object.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: but the point is I still have to get `LastPingedAt` ! For that I need to fetch all the values

Comment: @saplingPro, you don't need to get LastPingedAt.  Instead, you send the current time to the database in your SQL query, and let it do the calculation of 3 minutes.  This is what I showed in my example.

Comment: For a [table like](http://i50.tinypic.com/x0tkw4.jpg) and a [query similar to your's I get an error.](http://i45.tinypic.com/35iav7p.jpg)

Comment: @saplingPro, `values` is a reserved word in many DBs. Try naming the column something else or escaping it as appropriate on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The server knows it's current timestamp ("now"). So the query should select all rows where the "LastPingedAt" value is less then (now - 3*60*1000).

Something like

```
diff := now-180000
select LastPingedAt from JustPinged where LastPingedAt < diff
```

(pseudocode)

Comment: That is a good point.  However, this solution may also require changing the design of the code that sets the LastPingedAt column.  It is currently set from a Java timestamp (I think), which might not be the same format.